# Pick files from Storage account based on Datetimestamp Column using Data Factory

Tags: azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I have requirement to Copy files from Azure Storage account into other storage account based on Timestamp associated with files using Azure data Factory based on below condition .

So whenever Data Factory triggered copy activity should copy files based on file's timestamp column between 7PM UTC to 8AM UTC.

Suppose we have below files into Storage

**FileName**      **TimeStamp**

File1 -----> 2021-11-01 6.30PM

File2 -----> 2021-11-01 9.00PM

File3 -----> 2021-11-02 6.00AM

So In above scenario my copy activity should pull File2 and File3 based on its timestamp . Since its present between 8PM to 7AM.

I have tried to implement the same using **Filter by last modified Start time (UTC)** option in copy activity but my expression not validating correctly .

Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: could you please post any error message in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Input date format: 2021-11-04 11:53:00.0000000 then you need to use 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' in your `toTimeStamp` function, so you could try something like this - **toTimestamp('2021-11-04 11:53:00.000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')** in your code to convert it to required format.

[image]

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory

[image]